# Couldn't find /clock topic

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I want to get the simulation time published on the clock topic because the current time in ROS is set by default in the system time of the machine!!

The problem is that I can't find any topic named /clock or a parameter named use_sim_time here is what I get:

rostopic list:

```
/bebop/autoflight/navigate_home
/bebop/autoflight/pause
/bebop/autoflight/start
/bebop/autoflight/stop
/bebop/bebop_nodelet/parameter_descriptions
/bebop/bebop_nodelet/parameter_updates
/bebop/bebop_nodelet_manager/bond
/bebop/camera_control
/bebop/camera_info
/bebop/cmd_vel
/bebop/fix
/bebop/flattrim
/bebop/flip
/bebop/image_raw
/bebop/image_raw/compressed
/bebop/image_raw/compressed/parameter_descriptions
/bebop/image_raw/compressed/parameter_updates
/bebop/image_raw/compressedDepth
/bebop/image_raw/compressedDepth/parameter_descriptions
/bebop/image_raw/compressedDepth/parameter_updates
/bebop/image_raw/theora
/bebop/image_raw/theora/parameter_descriptions
/bebop/image_raw/theora/parameter_updates
/bebop/joint_states
/bebop/land
/bebop/odom
/bebop/record
/bebop/reset
/bebop/set_exposure
/bebop/snapshot
/bebop/states/ardrone3/CameraState/Orientation
/bebop/states/ardrone3/GPSState/NumberOfSatelliteChanged
/bebop/states/ardrone3/MediaStreamingState/VideoEnableChanged
/bebop/states/ardrone3/PilotingState/AltitudeChanged
/bebop/states/ardrone3/PilotingState/AttitudeChanged
/bebop/states/ardrone3/PilotingState/FlatTrimChanged
/bebop/states/ardrone3/PilotingState/FlyingStateChanged
/bebop/states/ardrone3/PilotingState/NavigateHomeStateChanged
/bebop/states/ardrone3/PilotingState/PositionChanged
/bebop/states/ardrone3/PilotingState/SpeedChanged
/bebop/states/common/CommonState/BatteryStateChanged
/bebop/states/common/CommonState/WifiSignalChanged
/bebop/states/common/FlightPlanState/AvailabilityStateChanged
/bebop/states/common/FlightPlanState/ComponentStateListChanged
/bebop/states/common/MavlinkState/MavlinkFilePlayingStateChanged
/bebop/states/common/MavlinkState/MavlinkPlayErrorStateChanged
/bebop/states/common/OverHeatState/OverHeatChanged
/bebop/takeoff
/rosout
/rosout_agg
/tf
/tf_static
```

rosparam list:

```
/bebop/bebop_nodelet/GPSSettingsHomeTypeType
/bebop/bebop_nodelet/GPSSettingsReturnHomeDelayDelay
/bebop/bebop_nodelet/NetworkSettingsWifiSelectionBand
/bebop/bebop_nodelet/NetworkSettingsWifiSelectionChannel
/bebop/bebop_nodelet/NetworkSettingsWifiSelectionType
/bebop/bebop_nodelet/PictureSettingsVideoFramerateFramerate
/bebop/bebop_nodelet/PictureSettingsVideoRecordingModeMode
/bebop/bebop_nodelet/PictureSettingsVideoResolutionsType
/bebop/bebop_nodelet/PictureSettingsVideoStabilizationModeMode
/bebop/bebop_nodelet/PilotingSettingsAbsolutControlOn
/bebop/bebop_nodelet/PilotingSettingsBankedTurnValue
/bebop/bebop_nodelet/PilotingSettingsCirclingAltitudeValue
/bebop/bebop_nodelet/PilotingSettingsCirclingDirectionValue
/bebop/bebop_nodelet/PilotingSettingsCirclingRadiusValue
/bebop/bebop_nodelet/PilotingSettingsMaxAltitudeCurrent
/bebop/bebop_nodelet/PilotingSettingsMaxDistanceValue
/bebop/bebop_nodelet/PilotingSettingsMaxTiltCurrent
/bebop/bebop_nodelet/PilotingSettingsMinAltitudeCurrent
/bebop/bebop_nodelet/PilotingSettingsNoFlyOverMaxDistanceShouldnotflyover
/bebop/bebop_nodelet/PilotingSettingsPitchModeValue
/bebop/bebop_nodelet/SpeedSettingsHullProtectionPresent
/bebop/bebop_nodelet/SpeedSettingsMaxPitchRollRotationSpeedCurrent
/bebop/bebop_nodelet/SpeedSettingsMaxRotationSpeedCurrent
/bebop/bebop_nodelet/SpeedSettingsMaxVerticalSpeedCurrent
/bebop/bebop_nodelet/SpeedSettingsOutdoorOutdoor
/bebop/bebop_nodelet/bebop_ip
/bebop/bebop_nodelet/camera_info_url
/bebop/bebop_nodelet/cmd_vel_timeout
/bebop/bebop_nodelet/odom_frame_id
/bebop/bebop_nodelet/publish_odom_tf
/bebop/bebop_nodelet/reset_settings
/bebop/bebop_nodelet/states/enable_altitudechanged
/bebop/bebop_nodelet/states/enable_autotakeoffmodechanged
/bebop/bebop_nodelet/states/enable_camerastate_orientation
/bebop/bebop_nodelet/states/enable_commonstate_batterystatechanged
/bebop/bebop_nodelet/states/enable_commonstate_wifisignalchanged
/bebop/bebop_nodelet/states/enable_controllerstate_ispilotingchanged
```

My purpose is to generate a sinosoidal trajectory with cos( pi t) and the time t here has to be set to 0 when the simulation starts.

Any suggestion please !!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/332015/couldn%27t-find-/clock-topic/) by [rayane](https://answers.ros.org/users/30174/rayane/) on ROS Answers with karma: 27 on 2019-08-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can check the clock [documentation](http://wiki.ros.org/Clock) and this [question](https://answers.ros.org/question/288672/how-use_sim_time-works/) regarding the `/clock` topic and `use_sim_time` parameter. Basically you need something like a rosbag or simulation to publish on the /clock topic.

If you are using Gazebo check this [question](https://answers.ros.org/question/255683/gazebo-is-not-publishing-clock/) and [documentation](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials/?tut=ros_comm).
Regarding rosbags, check this [question](https://answers.ros.org/question/12577/when-should-i-need-clock-parameter-on-rosbag-play/).

---

Originally posted by [pavel92](https://answers.ros.org/users/32610/pavel92/) with karma: 1655 on 2019-08-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rayane](https://answers.ros.org/users/30174/rayane/) on 2019-08-30**:
@pavel92 thanks for your answer

But my problem is that the parameter use_sim_time doesn't exist theck please the listed parameters shown in the question area and also the topics there is no such a topic named /clock .

**Comment by [pavel92](https://answers.ros.org/users/32610/pavel92/) on 2019-08-30**:
The parameter exists, just is not set. Try setting it with:

```
rosparam set use_sim_time true
```

and then `rosparam list` will show it.

**Comment by [rayane](https://answers.ros.org/users/30174/rayane/) on 2019-08-30**:
@pavel92 thanks it shows now the parameter!!
Maybe I didn't ask the question correctly!! How can I manage to get the data from two topics after 0.1 seconds!!! because the subscriber gets the message when it is available but we can't set it to get a message each 0.1 seconds!! I hope I made it clear enough. Thanks

**Comment by [pavel92](https://answers.ros.org/users/32610/pavel92/) on 2019-08-30**:
This is completely different question from the one you initially asked. If the answer helped you solve your initial problem you can accept it as correct. Otherwise regarding your follow-up question you can check ros [timers](http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Timers) (Timers let you schedule a callback to happen at a specific rate through the same callback queue mechanism used by subscription, service, etc. callbacks. ). 
If timers cant solve your problem then I suggest asking a new question.